# Russian/East-European/Soviet Cartoon show with 3 main characters

Tags: identify-this-tv-show, animation

I used to watch this show when I was a kid back in 1984.

The show is in color. No dialogue, only music and sound effects.

The characters are: a boy, his grandfather, and a bird (possibly a crow, but I think I remember its color: green.. not sure). And both the boy and his grandfather live in a house with no other member of the family.

I vaguely remember one episode in which a faucet became a character and it was determined to annoy the other characters and that they were trying to stop it from leaking..

The show is very old, it could have been made in the 60s.

I am not sure if the next bit of information is relevant, but it was aired on Saudi Arabian Channel 1 or 2 and never again aired after that.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're probably after **Pomysłowy Dobromir** from the 70s, a dialogue-free Polish cartoon about a boy who lives with his grandfather and a pet bird and always comes up with inventions. I think the episode you're describing is this one, only it's a hand pump, not a faucet:

Comment: Thank you so very much indeed. I have been looking for this video for more than 30 years... You are a genius. Thanks again